# Bash: Pass variable to other server in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have controller node (CN) and server nodes (SN). From CN, I need to config the hostname of each and every SN. `inv` file contains list of SNs and corresponding hostname.

In below script, I am not sure how to pass `hostname` variable. Any best way to achieve same?

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='\n'

for data in `awk 'NR>1 {print}' inv`
do
        ip=`awk '{print $1}' <<< $data`
        hostname=`awk '{print $2}' <<< $data`
        ssh root@$ip "hostnamectl set-hostname $hostname"
done
```

inv file,

```
IPs                     Hostname
172.31.98.11            Server1
172.31.106.177          Server2
172.31.97.105           Server3
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? `hostnamectl` on the server should already be called with the correct value (the variable is expanded before the string is sent the server. Does the variable contain the correct value?

Comment: What is a "bash server"?

Comment: @stickybit other bash server. I changed title now.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I still don't understand. Why (and where) do you need the variable on the other server? You only execute a single command and it has the variable's value already expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `awk` here since you are just printing all rows after 1st record. A `tail` does that job.

You may use this bash script:

```sh
while read -r ip hn; do
   ssh root@"$ip" "hostnamectl set-hostname $hn"
done < <(tail -n +2 inv)
```

Comment: can you pls explain `done < <(tail -n +2 inv)` I unable to understand why **< <** and space b/w them.

Comment: `< <(...)` is called process substitution. [Read more about it](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)